# Advanced SQL statement to detect non changing values - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables described below. What I need is a single query that will tell me the players whose score hasn't changed in a given number of days.

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  pid INT(50),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  updatedAt DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE pl_scores (
  pid INT(50),
  score INT(255),
  updatedAt DATETIME
);
```

The `players` table keeps a master list of all players along with other non-changing data not shown here for the sake of brevity. The `pl_scores` table keeps a running history of score changes in order to track growth and other values that might change. A new record is inserted into `pl_scores` for each player every 6 hours.

What I would like to get is the `pid` of the players that haven't had a change of score in a certain number of days, but I am unsure of how to group that in order to get the correct values.

**Example dataset**

(only shows last score of each day which is only one needing to be compared really)

```
+------+------+-------+------+---------+---------------------+
| pid  | aid  | score | rank | cityCnt | updatedAt           |
+------+------+-------+------+---------+---------------------+
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2111 |       1 | 2012-06-20 22:14:11 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2250 |       1 | 2012-06-21 22:15:45 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2387 |       1 | 2012-06-22 22:17:06 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2547 |       1 | 2012-06-23 22:17:09 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2702 |       1 | 2012-06-24 22:19:50 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2836 |       1 | 2012-06-25 22:21:07 |
| 1660 |    0 |   801 | 2956 |       1 | 2012-06-26 21:42:44 |
+------+------+-------+------+---------+---------------------+
```

**EDIT**

The answer found below worked perfectly, but now I'd like to take it a step further and limit the results by a hardcoded value found in a 3rd table. Here is the working SQL statement

```
SELECT a.pid, c.aid, b.name AS pName, c.name AS aName, a.score FROM pl_scores AS a 
JOIN players AS b ON a.pid = b.pid 
JOIN alliances AS c ON b.aid = c.aid 
WHERE a.updatedAt >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY GROUP BY a.pid HAVING MIN(a.score) = MAX(a.score);
```

Each player has multiple cities throughout the world. I'd like to limit the results by players with cities found on a given continent. For example, I want to find every player that hasn't changed their score in the last 3 days on continent `34`. The `cities` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
  cid INT(50),
  pid INT(50),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  cont INT(10),
  updatedAt DATETIME
);
```

Comment: It is not really clear how `cities` is related to `pl_scores`.

Comment: oh sorry, there's a pid column also that directly relates to it (EDITED)

Comment: That's useful, but so far I can only tell that this city belongs to this user. But how could I tell which score change was related to that particular city? Should I use `updatedAt` to link the two things together? Or maybe I'm misinterpreting your question and that relationship isn't needed...

Comment: individual city score is irrelevant (but there is a score table that mimics the `pl_scores` called `ci_scores`). The idea is to find inactive players that are on a given continent, not inactive cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get `pid`s of players with their scores unchanged like this:

```
SELECT pid
FROM pl_scores
WHERE updatedAt >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL n DAY
GROUP BY pid
HAVING MIN(score) = MAX(score)
```

Now you can use those `pid`s to get full (or just more) information about the corresponding players, i.e. like this:

```
SELECT *  /* or you could specify the necessary columns here */
FROM players
WHERE pid IN (  
  SELECT pid
  FROM pl_scores
  WHERE updatedAt >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL n DAY
  GROUP BY pid
  HAVING MIN(score) = MAX(score)
)
```

Comment: this gave me a syntax error near `DAYS GROUP BY pid HAVING MIN(score) = MAX(score)`

Comment: perfect, now I need to take it a step further and limit it by a value found in a 3rd table if you want to go for extra credit :) (see edit in post)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it can be done with something like this:

```
      SELECT plf.pid, 
             COALESCE(plf.score, 0) AS former_score, 
             COALESCE(pll.score, 0) AS latter_score
        FROM pl_scores AS plf
  RIGHT JOIN (
             SELECT pid, score FROM pl_scores 
             WHERE DATE(updatedAt) = DATE(NOW())
             ) as pll
          ON plf.pid = pll.pid
       WHERE DATE(updatedAt) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) 
      HAVING former_score = latter_score
```

Comment: I'm guessing %somedate% should be replaced with an actual DATETIME time stamp? This as is gives a syntax error...I'm not needing a specific date, but rather the scores that haven't changed in the last 2 days or 3 days...the number of days can be hardcoded into the query.

Comment: Updated the answer. Yes, %somedate% was to be replaced by some DATETIME literal. It can be rewritten, though, so that joined will be the `former` result set.

Comment: It returned an empty set although there are several records with identical scores, updated my post to reflect one such record found in pl_scores

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question: somehow I suppose we need to get records with NOT identical scores. Easy to fix: just change `!=` to `=`.

Comment: I'm wanting the ones with identical scores, but either way it returns an empty result set, no matching records found.

Comment: ... but there's another one: right now we check for strict equality of  updatedAt (as I guessed the new rows are inserted in exactly the same time), but from what I see in your example, time component here is not equal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13201/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-pastor-bones)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.pid, c.aid, b.name AS pName, c.name AS aName, a.score FROM pl_scores AS a 
JOIN players AS b ON a.pid = b.pid 
JOIN alliances AS c ON b.aid = c.aid 
JOIN cities AS d ON a.pid = d.pid
WHERE 
a.updatedAt >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
AND d.cont = 34
GROUP BY a.pid HAVING MIN(a.score) = MAX(a.score);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work:

`SELECT pid, MIN(updatedAt) AS last FROM pl_scores GROUP BY pid, score HAVING last > '2012-06-24'`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your `updatedAt` contains when an entry was made and not the update time, using 3 days as the time to check:

```
SELECT pid FROM
    (SELECT * FROM pl_score GROUP BY pid HAVING updatedAt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND COUNT(DISTINCT(score)) = 1) AS y
JOIN pl_score ON y.pid = pl_score.pid;
```

Read [this page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) to learn more about this sort of problem.

I can't guarantee that this'll work, but give it a try.

Comment: I've changed the code to work on a basis of how many days instead of how many entries. Ironically enough, it's also cut down on the amount of code substantially.

Comment: nope didn't work: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Dammit. It's really hard writing code that works when you have no way of testing it. I've re-edited it; keeping my fingers crossed (since I have no way of knowing if it'll work; logic says it should though)...